# NetworkManager fails to auto-connect to WiFi network when the password is kept in the GNOME Keyring

Tags: networking, arch-linux, systemd, wifi

By default the NetworkManager stores WiFi passwords in plain text in `*.nmconnection` files inside `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`. This is not acceptable for me, so I decided to edit my connection by using `nm-connection-editor`. There I checked the `Store the password only for this user` option. This has the effect of storing the password in the GNOME Keyring instead of plain text.

But there is a problem with this solution: the NetworkManager is started as a systemd unit upon computer boot. At this time the GNOME Keyring isn't even started yet. It will be started later by my display manager upon successful login and automatically unlocked with my user password (which is the same as keyring's password). So, obviously, NetworkManager fails to fetch the password from the keyring, emmitting the following log:

`NetworkManager[610]: <warn>  [1565208122.6857] device (wlp2s0): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.`

After I login there is no WiFi connection. I have to click the nm-applet and choose my WiFi network. After this it is connected, but I would prefer if it happened automatically.

Is it a problem with my configuration? If so, how can I fix it?

For completeness here is my configuration:

- OS: Arch Linux
- Display Manager: SDDM
- Window Manager: i3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing NetworkManager's source code I've found the problem. NetworkManager will block the connection from auto-connect if it can't get secrets from the keyring. It looks like this behavior is non-configurable and is hardcoded in nm-policy.c:

https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/master/src/nm-policy.c

Near line 1830 there is a following piece of code:

```
if (nm_device_state_reason_check (reason) == NM_DEVICE_STATE_REASON_NO_SECRETS) {
    /* ... */
    con_v = nm_settings_connection_get_last_secret_agent_version_id (sett_conn);
    if (   con_v == 0
        || con_v == nm_agent_manager_get_agent_version_id (priv->agent_mgr))
            block_no_secrets = TRUE;
}

if (block_no_secrets) {
    _LOGD (LOGD_DEVICE, "connection '%s' now blocked from autoconnect due to no secrets",
        nm_settings_connection_get_id (sett_conn));
        nm_settings_connection_autoconnect_blocked_reason_set (sett_conn, NM_SETTINGS_AUTO_CONNECT_BLOCKED_REASON_NO_SECRETS, TRUE);
}
```

The easiest way to hack around this behavior and make NetworkManager NOT block the connection from auto-connect is to not set the `block_no_secrets` to TRUE (just set it to FALSE or remove the first if statement altogether).